# HTM5 VIDEO TAG is not working

Tags: html, video

this is my **HTML**

```
            <video controls>
                  <source src="videos/video1.mp4" loop type="video/mp4">
            </video>
```

it plays, I hear its audio but the video didnt show up.. PLEASE HELP...

Comment: what's the codec used for you video file? It must be h.264 to be read properly in mp4 container

Comment: how to code codec... i dont know how...

Comment: When you exported your video, with any software you used, you might have an option for codec which will encode it

Comment: i have mp4 file in my folder videos, do i need to use codec?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format

Comment: will u give me some example on how to use codec...

Comment: no. Read the linked articles, search the web, and ask the one who made the video files to export it in h.264

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please try to implement with the below code

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Have you included html5 doctype <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 0):

First try it with some other video on your PC, if it works then you can apply for your video.

```
<video id="tutorials" autoplay  controls>
<source src="testing.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```